# Function to find the rectangle angle of the triangle that contains a given point

Tags: geometry, webgl

[diagram explaining the case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2m8P.png)

In a webgl / fragment shader context.
I have a uv space. Is filled of right angle triangles as the image shows.
Notice that "c0" is at 0.5 , 0.5.
"ac" side is 0.25
"bc" side is 0.1666 (1/6)
I looking a way to, given a point "p" in uv coordinates, obtain the coordinates of the right angle "c" of the triangle that contains that point.

Edit: Im working in webgl and looking for a function like:
vec2 getAngleC(vec2 p)

I tried creating the function by my self and using ChatGPT 4 which seams to get confused.

Comment: What is a "rectangle angle"? So you have point p, and you want to know the coordinates of the right angle triangle that point p lies in? Can you include what you tried? It's a little challenging because of the strange way you've split up your rectangle.

Comment: Sorry @matt you are right. "rectangle angle" is actually a "right angle (90º)".
This problem is a simplification of this other in webgl: https://ibb.co/mTxy16f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find the square that the point lies in.

```
x = Math.trunc(u/ac);
y = Math.trunc(v/bc);
```

That gives you the index of the square. We can use local coordinates within the square.

```
lx = u - x*ac;
ly = v - y*bc;
```

Next you have to find which way the diagonal line is going. Lets call top left to bottom right "even" and top right to bottom left "odd".

```
sig = (x%2 + y%2)%2;
```

If the sig is 0, then you have an even square. (as in your example). Which means the line going through the square is defined as.

```
h = bc - lx*bc/ac;
if( ly > h ){
    cx = (x+1) * ac;
    cy = (y+1)* bc;
} else{
    cx = x*ac;
    cy = y*bc;
}
```

cx and cy are the u,v coordinates of right angle of interest.

Case 2. Odd. We do the same think.

```
h = lx*bc/ac;

if(ly > h){
    cx = x*ac;
    cy = (y + 1)*bc;
} else{
    cx = (x+1)*ac;
    cy = y*bc;
}
```

I hope that helps. I made some assumptions about your problem and assumed you're using javascript. Maybe this is in the shader though and you might need to change a little bit.